# How to manipulate summations and subscripts using sympy for solving ODEs (Frobenius)?

Tags: python, math, sympy, ode

I am building a small library which aims to solve differential equations of the form covered in my undergrad class. I am currently trying to create a function which solves Frobenius equations of the form:

P(x)y'' + Q(x)y' + R(x)y = 0 (*)

To solve an equation of this form, we assume a solution of the form:

y = sum_{n=0}^{oo} a_n * x^{n+r}

Then substitute y into (*). Below is an example of how this is done:

[image: Example working out]

My question consists of 2 parts:

1. Is it possible to create a symbolic y in sympy, i.e. a summation of terms with unknown coefficients a_n and terms x^{n+r}, whose subscripts and superscripts can be manipulated. For example, changing a_n to a_{m-2} or x^{n+r+1} to x^{m+r}? And if so, how?
2. Is it possible to identify which x term has the largest superscript, and also extract what the superscript is? In the case of the image, identifying that the largest superscript is n+r+1

Comment: I don't see any `sympy` code

Comment: @hpaulj That is because I am asking for help in writing the sympy code and so currently don't have any. I wanted to see what people's suggestions for answering my two questions in sympy would be

Answer (score 1):

This is a start:

```
In [6]: y = Function('y')

In [7]: x = Symbol('x')

In [8]: ode = x*(x-1)*y(x).diff(x, x) + 6*x**2*y(x).diff(x) + 3*y(x)

In [9]: ode
Out[9]: 
                            2               
   2 d                     d                
6⋅x ⋅──(y(x)) + x⋅(x - 1)⋅───(y(x)) + 3⋅y(x)
     dx                     2               
                          dx                

In [10]: a = IndexedBase('a')

In [11]: r, n = symbols('r, n', integer=True)

In [12]: ysol = Sum(a[n]*x**(r + n), (n, 0, oo))

In [13]: ysol
Out[13]: 
  ∞              
 ___             
 ╲               
  ╲    n + r     
  ╱   x     ⋅a[n]
 ╱               
 ‾‾‾             
n = 0            

In [14]: ode.subs(y(x), ysol)
Out[14]: 
       ⎛  ∞              ⎞                ⎛  ∞              ⎞       ∞              
       ⎜ ___             ⎟                ⎜ ___             ⎟      ___             
       ⎜ ╲               ⎟               2⎜ ╲               ⎟      ╲               
   2 ∂ ⎜  ╲    n + r     ⎟              ∂ ⎜  ╲    n + r     ⎟       ╲    n + r     
6⋅x ⋅──⎜  ╱   x     ⋅a[n]⎟ + x⋅(x - 1)⋅───⎜  ╱   x     ⋅a[n]⎟ + 3⋅  ╱   x     ⋅a[n]
     ∂x⎜ ╱               ⎟               2⎜ ╱               ⎟      ╱               
       ⎜ ‾‾‾             ⎟             ∂x ⎜ ‾‾‾             ⎟      ‾‾‾             
       ⎝n = 0            ⎠                ⎝n = 0            ⎠     n = 0            

In [15]: _.doit()
Out[15]: 
                                                                 ∞                                  
                                                                ___                                 
                                                                ╲                                   
       ∞                                                         ╲    n + r                         
      ____                           ∞                 (x - 1)⋅  ╱   x     ⋅(n + r)⋅(n + r - 1)⋅a[n]
      ╲                             ___                         ╱                                   
       ╲    n + r                   ╲                           ‾‾‾                                 
   2    ╲  x     ⋅(n + r)⋅a[n]       ╲    n + r                n = 0                                
6⋅x ⋅   ╱  ─────────────────── + 3⋅  ╱   x     ⋅a[n] + ─────────────────────────────────────────────
       ╱            x               ╱                                        x                      
      ╱                             ‾‾‾                                                             
      ‾‾‾‾                         n = 0                                                            
     n = 0
```

From here there are various functions that you can use to manipulate this like `expand`, `expand_mul`, `factor_terms`, `collect` etc. Fiddling the indices is probably something that would require a bit of manual code.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have not been able to tackle the problem yet but once I get a chance to, I'll give your method a go and respond back to you!